# How to change woocommerce mini cart total (based on product name instead of quantity)?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

as per title mention, right now the minicart is showing total based on the total quantity of the products, but not product name (ID). I assume it should be changed under "mini-cart.php" (correct me if I'm wrong). Can anyone tell me how and where to change this code? Thanks

refer here: https://shop.cheesang.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/sample.jpg

```
<?php
/**
 * Mini-cart
 *
 * Contains the markup for the mini-cart, used by the cart widget.
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/cart/mini-cart.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you (the theme developer).
 * will need to copy the new files to your theme to maintain compatibility. We try to do this.
 * as little as possible, but it does happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will.
 * be bumped and the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see     http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author  WooThemes
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 2.5.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_mini_cart' ); ?>

<ul class="cart_list products-list product_list_widget <?php echo $args['list_class']; ?>">

    <?php if ( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ) : ?>

        <?php
            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
                $_product     = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                $product_id   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

                if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_widget_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {

                    $product_name  = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_title(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                    $thumbnail     = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                    $product_price = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', WC()->cart->get_product_price( $_product ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                    ?>
                    <li>
                        <?php if ( ! $_product->is_visible() ) : ?>
                            <?php echo str_replace( array( 'http:', 'https:' ), '', $thumbnail ) . $product_name . '&nbsp;'; ?>
                        <?php else : ?>
                            <a class="title" href="<?php echo esc_url( $_product->get_permalink( $cart_item ) ); ?>">
                                <?php echo str_replace( array( 'http:', 'https:' ), '', $thumbnail ) . $product_name . '&nbsp;'; ?>
                            </a>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php echo WC()->cart->get_item_data( $cart_item ); ?>

                        <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_widget_cart_item_quantity', '<span class="quantity">' . sprintf( '%s &times; %s', $cart_item['quantity'], $product_price ) . '</span>', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); ?>
                        <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link', sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="remove" title="%s"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></a>', esc_url( WC()->cart->get_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ), __( 'Remove this item', 'snssimen' ) ), $cart_item_key ); ?>
                    </li>
                    <?php
                }
            }
        ?>

    <?php else : ?>

        <li class="empty"><?php _e( 'No products in the cart.', 'snssimen' ); ?></li>

    <?php endif; ?>

</ul><!-- end product list -->

<?php if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) : ?>

    <p class="total"><?php _e( 'Total', 'snssimen' ); ?>: <strong><?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal(); ?></strong></p>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_before_buttons' ); ?>

    <p class="buttons">
        <a href="<?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_url(); ?>" class="button wc-forward"><?php _e( 'Go to Cart', 'snssimen' ); ?></a>
        <a href="<?php echo WC()->cart->get_checkout_url(); ?>" class="button checkout wc-forward"><?php _e( 'Checkout', 'snssimen' ); ?></a>
    </p>
    <span style="display:none" class="sns-cart-number">
        <?php echo sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) ?>
        <?php //echo $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count; ?>
    </span>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_mini_cart' ); ?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [this checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and edit your question accordingly. It will help to get a valuable feedback

Answer (score 0):

add this code in functions.php file

```
//This function will display total qty ni mini-cart 

function filter__woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments($fragments) {
    ob_start(); ?>
    <div class="number bold">
        <?php echo sprintf( '%d', WC()->cart->cart_contents_count ); ?>
    </div>

    <?php
    $fragments['#minicart .number'] = ob_get_clean();
    return $fragments;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'filter__woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments' );
```

And to show mini-cart in header add this code in header.php file

```
<div class="mini-cart">
    <a id="minicart" href="<?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_url(); ?>" class="cart icon red relative">
        <div class="number boldd">
            <?php echo sprintf('%d', WC()->cart->cart_contents_count); ?>
        </div>
        <div id="cartcontents">
            <div class="widget_shopping_cart_content">
                <?php woocommerce_mini_cart(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for reply but it doesn't work....i already have that mini cart. what i want here is that the total show is total product ID instead of quantity. For example in the image attached, it should show total 2 products instead of total quantity 4. Thanks